# Getting error "Can't set IN parameter for return value of stored function call" in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

I have created stored procure in MySQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN TO_CREATE BIGINT,OUT CREATED BIGINT)
BEGIN
    -- doing some operation ---
END
```

and i am trying to call this procedure like

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<sql-query name="domain_test" read-only="false" callable="true" cacheable="false"><![CDATA[
        { ? = CALL TEST(?) }
    ]]></sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

After deploying on jboss with MySQL , i am getting following error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't set IN parameter for return value of stored function call.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
```

It is working on DB2 and PostgreSQL  . Any difference in MySQL with respect to hibernate ? Any suggestion or help ?

Comment: there error means the stored procedure expects this parameter to be input only IN.  The parameter needs to be defined on the procedure as INOUT  input/output.

Comment: In is probably a reserved word.

Comment: Then how will it solve this error ? If i use `INOUT` for `IN` , will it resolve ?

Comment: I would refactor the procedure with parmameter names inBigInt and outBigInt.

Comment: I see an error in the procedure create statement too.  CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN TO_CREATE BIGINT,OUT CREATED BIGINT)
BEGIN  you have "out created bigint).  Consider not using the underscore character ever.  It will come up again as it has already in the procedure.